# Sass - Get rid of quotes around string generated by inspect

Tags: css, sass

In this minimal sass example I try to concatenate a string and a string generated by `inspect()`

```scss
// Can not be changed:
@function get-filename() {
    $filename: inspect("foo.jpg");
    @return $filename;
}

// My code:
$url: "path/" + get-filename(); 
body {
    background-image: url($url);
}
```

However this doesn't resolve as required, because there are quotes around `foo.jpg`

```css
body {
  background-image: url('path/"foo.jpg"');
}
```

Can you tell me how to correct my code such that the resolving css is:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('path/foo.jpg');
}
```

As stated in the comment, in my application I cannot change the function that generates `$filename`.

I though that this could be solved with `$url: "path/" + unquote(get-filename());` but this doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unquote` should work here but that looks to be a bug in Sass itself when combining it with the result of `inspect`.

You could potentially use a function to drop the first and last character in the string:

```
// Can not be changed:
@function get-filename() {
    $filename: inspect("foo.jpg");
    @return $filename;
}

@function dropOuterCharacters($input) {
    @return str-slice($input, 2, str-length($input) - 1);
}

$url: "path/" + dropOuterCharacters(get-filename()); 
body {
    background-image: url($url);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there's a better solution. But if that's not the case this workaround does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it's a bit of a hacky work around for this kind of bug. Hopefully they fix it in future versions of Sass.